# How to include proxy auth username and password for proxy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I do not want to give username/password for proxy setting I have for my office network, I could give PROXY to browser either :

```java
String PROXY = "localhost:8080";

org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
     .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
     .setSslProxy(PROXY);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabailities();
cap.setPreference(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
```

or

```java
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1");
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 8084);
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl", "127.0.0.1");
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8084);
user_pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost:4444");
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

but, what ever I do, its still asking for password for Webdriver.
Note: I could send username/password for htmlunit driver. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: looking for help from experts...

Comment: I feel for you, I'm trying to find the answer as well but had no luck yet. @Bijoy, it's been a month, have you figured out how to do it? Hopefully you can help me out.

Comment: the only way to do it in current webdriver ( with firefox driver ) is to set these in a firefox profile and then use that profile as the source profile for starting the webdriver. I actually had to patch selenium to be able to set them at run time. I'm hoping to be able to extract the patches and publish them in the following days

Comment: Is there any way to do it now?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
 profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0); 
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read a lot of posts stating that you have to send the profile as a base64 encoded string.

```
cap.setPreference(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy.ToBase64String());
```

The documentation I've read hasn't ever been conclusive if this is necessary or not, but it's worth a shot.